# xpath and xslt ... what is child::para?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm *very very* new to XML, HTML and XSLT.

I am studying notes for a class on XSLT and there is a chunk on xpath. The notes say:
These are some examples of location paths using the unabbreviated syntax:
- child::para
- child::*

And there are about 30 more. I don't get what this is saying. Would I literally type "child::para", like are these key words, or do I put what I have as tags in my XML document?

Let's say I have this simple xml document:

```
<school>
 <university>
   <western>purple</western>
   <toronto>blue</toronto>
 </university>
 <highschool>
   <northern>red</norther>
   <scits>blue</scits>
 </highschool>
</school>
```

How would I select out the "purple" for example? Would I say school::child::para? I really don't get how to use xpath to get particular nodes/tag/elements... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its important to know that XPath is a query language that still requires something to run it, like an XML engine, much akin to SQL (the **S**tructured **Q**uery **L**anguage) needs an SQL server to run.

As for your question, any number of Queries could be constructed to extract `"purple"` from that document.

As simple as:

```
/school/university/western/text()
```

However, this only works if I know that this is the exact path. If I think that all `western` nodes are "purple", I can just find all of those wherever they are in the document.

```
//western/text()
```

But, what if I only want universities:

```
//university/western/text()
```

Or I might want to know what divisions are "purple" - note this query returns the parent nodes that "are purple" not the text itself.:

```
//university//*[text()="purple"]
```

The `::` syntax is for using [XPath axes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (plural of axis, not axe). `child::para` says find the child elements of the `para` element at the current context node. In your document `child::para` will find nothing as there are no `para` elements. Nor would `school::child::para` work as its invalidly laid out and `school::` is not a valid XPath axes.

This venn diagram from Umbraco gives a good idea of how axes work:

[image: Umbraco / Crane venn diagram of Xpath axes]

Comment: Okay great thanks! So do you never actually type the "::", do you always use "/", like you are writing out a path? (which given the name makes sense to me...)

Comment: @jcam77 It depends on what kinds of query you are doing, sometimes you use axes, sometimes not. It sounds like it might be worth reviewing your class notes again and perhaps do some more reading online.

Comment: *"child::para says find the child elements of the para element at the current context node."* That's not quite right.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm very very new to XML, HTML and XSLT.
>
> I am studying notes for a class on XSLT and there is a chunk on xpath.

The notes you have been given are obviously sketchy. I wonder if asking on SO is really your best learning strategy. There are lots of tutorials on the web, and lots of books which are hopefully in your college library. I think you should be doing a bit more reading and only come here if you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right: `child::para` is not a good example, unless you are looking at an actual XML document that looks something like this:

```
<book>
    <chapter>
        <para>Lorem ipsum.</para>
        <para>Nam interdum.</para>
        <para>Cum sociis natoque.</para>
   </chapter>
   <chapter>
        <para>Ut molestie quam.</para>
        <para>Duis dapibus.</para>
   </chapter>
</book>
```

Only then it becomes apparent that `child` is an **axis** (and its name does not depend on the currently processed document) and `para` is a **node** that is (or is expected to be) found in the processed XML.

IOW, the generalized syntax is:

`axis::node`